# Best practices for dealing with ObjectId with mongo and Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, mongodb

I am developing an app with Mongo, Node.JS and Angular
Every time the object is delivered and handled in the front-end, all objectId's are converted to strings (this happens automatically when I send it as json), but when when I save objects back into mongo, I need to convert _id and any other manual references to other collections back to ObjectID objects. If I want to nicely separate database layer from the rest of my backend, it becomes even more messy, lets assume my database layer has the following signature:

```
database.getItem(itemId, callback)
```

I want my backend business treat itemId as opaque type (i.e no require'ing mongo or knowing anything about ObjectId outside of this database layer), yet at the same time I want to be able to take the result of this function and send it directly to
the frontend with express js.

```
exports.getItem = function(req, res) {
    database.getItem(req.params.id, function(err, item) {
        res.json(item);
    });
};
```

What I end up doing now is:

```
exports.getItem = function(itemId, callback) {
    if (typeof itemId == 'string') {
        itemId = new ObjectID(itemId);
    }
    var query = {_id: itemId};

    items.findOne(query, callback);
};
```

This way it can handle both calls which come from within the backend, where itemId reference might be coming from another object and thus might already be in the right binary format, as well as requests with string itemId's.

As I already mentioned above, when I am saving an object that came from front-end and which contains many manual references to other collections that is even more painful, since I need to go over the object and change all id strings to ObjectIds.

This all feels very wrong, there must be a better way to do it. What is it?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at using [`Mongoose`](http://mongoosejs.com/)?  It handles this type casting for you.

Comment: I'm coming across the same issue. I have a very open-ended api that allows pretty arbitrary queries from the frontend, and it may well be impossible to know if something needs to be a string or an objectId. At very least I don't want to have to reimplement a good portion of mongo's query parsing code just to be sure that strings are converted to ObjectIds in all the appropriate places.

The best idea I've come up with so far is to convert _ids for known properties, and require unknown properties to always just be strings. This still would require combing through queries and replacing _ids tho

Comment: My question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27979012/best-ways-to-provide-a-very-open-ended-api-over-mongo-db-with-regards-to-objec