# Best way(s) to provide a very open-ended api over mongo db with regards to ObjectIds

Tags: mongodb, objectid

I have a very open-ended API that allows the frontend to query the backend with more-or-less arbitrary mongo queries. I'm having problems with _ids being stored as ObjectIds but passed around as hex strings. If the frontend gives me some complicated mongo query, I don't want to have to implement logic to comb through all the crazy mongo query operators to replace string _ids with ObjectIds.

Beyond that, objects in the system have user-defined schemas, and so there are cases where the backend *can't* know whether a certain field being queried should be an ObjectId or not.

Does anyone know how I could solve this problem? The best idea I've come up with so far is to always store strings instead of ObjectIds for user-defined fields, and to figure out how to parse mongo queries to replace string _ids with ObjectIds for known fields. This certainly isn't ideal, so I'm hoping there's a more elegant solution here.

Comment: Depends on your language implementation and library choice. The common approach is to give your app some concept of "schema" and let that code resolve the "string" to a correct  `ObjectId` type via coercion. There are libraries that assist you with doing this, or it's the basic principle to follow when "rolling your own".

Comment: The "coercion" you're talking about sounds like what I  mean when i say "comb through all the crazy mongo query operators".

Comment: Well as I also said "your language.. and library choice"(sic) For example there is [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) as one example ( not making any recommendation). But you can look at how that does it to an approach to using a "typed schema" to actually resolve other input (such as a string) to construct an object. Coercion is a common modern technique for object constructors.

Comment: I added a feature request here https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-16909